# How to get S3 url from Filepicker.io upon upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, filepicker.io

I am using Filepicker ruby gem to store images into my S3 folder, but when I store them, what I get back is a filepicker api/file url, which seems to store this file in a filepicker bucket anyway.

My S3 now contains the images, with their originals and the original file names, but there's no association between Filepicker URL and the S3 url.

The question is, how do I use Filepicker to put images into my S3 and then get the URL for that file from Filepicker (preferably while uploading via Filepicker).

p.s. Ideally, Filepicker shouldn't even hold a copy of my files, but should rather process and store directly to S3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have S3 correctly configured on your account then there is no additional configuration needed.

In order to check where your file is uploaded, you can paste the filepicker url in browser with appended "/metadata" path.

You should see information "location: S3" and "container: ". 
This means that the file was uploaded to your S3 and filepicker url points to it.

Comment: Thanks Maciej! Wasn't obvious, but it looks like everything is indeed working like desired. Didn't realize Filepicker was basically a symlink.